# Jquery and multiple AJAX calls on one page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have thumbnails on a page, as such:

```
<div id="credits">
<a href="largeimage1.jpg" alt="credits1.php"><img src="thumb1"></a>
<a href="largeimage2.jpg" alt="credits2.php"><img src="thumb2"></a>
<a href="largeimage3.jpg" alt="credits3.php"><img src="thumb3"></a>
</div>

<div id="zoom"></div>

<div id="credits"></div>
```

I'm looking to do the following:

- user clicks thumb1 > largeimage1 loads in #zoom AND credits1.php loads in #credits
- user clicks thumb2 > largeimage2 loads in #zoom AND credits2.php loads in #credits
- etc.

Is this possible with jquery?  ie. is it possible to make TWO (2) ajax calls on the same page with one click as in above?

I currently have the following code working for the LARGE image ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#zoom img").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).attr({ src: largePath }).fadeIn("slow");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and it works like a charm - but I now have a situation where I'd like to load up credits for the images in another div.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: you can do as many AJAX calls as you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above this line:

```
return false;
```

Add this:

```
$('#credits').load($(this).attr('alt'));
```

The whole point of asynchronous requests is that you can fire as many as you want while you keep going. You might want to have some kind of loading indicator that something is happening when you use load, as well as maybe some error handling, but the above should do the trick at a basic level.

Comment: I just noticed that I already have a class tag applied to the A HREF tag by the name "credits1".  Rather than adding an ALT tag and using that for the call, is it possible to tell jQuery to take the CLASS tag name and append ".php" to it and load that in the #credits div?  Do you understand what I mean?  So it would be like <code><a href="largeimage1" class="credits1"><img src="thumb1"></a></code>

Comment: Well, it is possible, but if you ever add another class then it wouldn't work. To do it, however, you would do: $('#credits').load($(this).attr('class'));

Comment: Paolo - the class tag doesn't have ".php" extension appended to its name - so we need to be able to append it so that a proper php file is called.

Right now, the class="credits1" - we need to have an ajax call for a file called "credits1.php".

Answer (score 1):

Mate, that's not ajax.  All it does is hide elements on the page by editing the css display:block; to display:none;

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I'm not missing something about jquery (I'm more familiar with mootools), your first bit of code won't work unless you have an image already inside the zoom div. I don't see anything in your code that injects a new image into the div... it only targets an existing image and updates its attributes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right actually. There should be an existing "img" tag in there so one can "inject" the src in there. it looks like i forgot to put that in there.

Comment: Thanks Mo, just wanted to make sure there wasn't some sort of auto-injection feature for selectors in jquery that I was missing. I could actually see jquery doing something like that, since they use the same methods for gets and sets (which I think is pretty cool).